# 3D Convolution in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, matrix, convolution

I'm currently trying to use convolution to average blocks in my data and turn my current, 336x264x25x27, grid into a new, 100x100x27, grid.

To achieve this I've been trying to use convolution.

In a 2-D setting I've been able to convert a 336x264 matrix to 100x100 using the conv2 function in matlab. I'm now trying to use convn to accomplish a similar task in 4-D.

As stated, currently I'm using the convn function. I'm trying to average out cells over the first two dimensions so that I end up with a 100x100x27 matrix. My code is as follows:

```
A = rand(336,264,25,27); % Sample Data
A = A(:,:,13,:); % This line and the following line eliminate the third dimension (time) which will be constant throughout my output. Now "A" is 336x264x27 after using "squeeze".
A = squeeze(A);
B = ones(100,100,27); % This is the size of matrix that I would like to achieve. I was under the impression that "B" was the size matrix that you want to inevitably end up with but I believe I am mistaken.
C = convn(A,B); % C would hopefully by my 100x100x27 matrix.
```

Currently, this is resulting in a 435x363x53 matrix. If you could help me with my logic and show me how I might turn "A" into a 100x100x27 matrix using convolution it would be much appreciated!

Comment: Just Edited this to show my code within a code block.

Comment: How did you do this in the 2D case? You probably want to do the same in 3D, with the kernel having size 1 along the 3rd dimension so you don’t smooth there.

Comment: You can read how to do that in the documentation: https://uk.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/convn.html#bvg3kvh-1-shape